# How to transform a map (tuple -> list) to (tuple, list)

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let's say I have a following Map:

```
Map((1,2,3) -> List(4, 5))
```

And now I would like to transform it to:

```
(1,2,3,List(4, 5))
```

How to do this functional way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val myMap = Map((1, 2, 3) -> List(4, 5))
val tuple = myMap map { case ((a, b, c), list) => (a, b, c, list) }
```

This will return you `Iterable[(Int, Int, Int, List[Int])]`, that is an `Iterable` of your `tuple`s of `1, 2, 3, List(4, 5)` ... If that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach,

```
aMap.toList
```